# Values in ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

I'm trying to put some values in the ckeditor textarea, like this:

```
<textarea name="notes" class="ckeditor" value="<?php echo $row['notes']; ?>" id="notes" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
```

It doesn't work. Any idea why? Version 4.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

you need to try with :

```
<textarea name="notes" class="ckeditor"  id="notes" rows="10" cols="80"><?php echo $row['notes']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: That's right, it's working now. The variable should be between <textarea, not in textarea values="".
Thank you!